# Zip Slip path traversal and consistent vulnerability checks

Tags: vulnerability, java, zip

According to multiple sources such as [snyk](https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability) and [infoq](https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/06/zip-slip/), preventing a "Zip Slip" vulnerability in Java can be achieved by denying writes outside the target directory:

```
String canonicalDestDirPath = destDir.getCanonicalPath();
File destfile = new File(destDir, e.getName());
String canonicalDestFile destfile.getCanonicalPath();
if (!canonicalDestFile.startsWith(canonicalDestDirPath + File.separator)) {
 throw new ArchiverException("Entry outside of the target dir");
}
```

This is indeed safe but has the non-ideal side effect that a zip archive containing a file with path `../tmp/file` is OK if extracted to `/tmp` but not anywhere else.
Wouldn't it be more consistent to prevent all path traversals that navigate out of ANY destination?
A more consistent check would allow to reliably mark a zip file as "tainted", independently of where it is going to be extracted.
Consistent checks would be an advantage when validation and extraction happen at a different time in a backend processing pipeline.

Two questions:

1. why are consistent checks not adopted more widely?
2. what would be a safe implementation of this stricter Zip Slip check?  I was thinking of setting `destDir = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()` in the above implementation.

Comment: Haven't most zip libraries fixed these issues by now?

Comment: *Most* 3rd party libraries, probably yes, but when using `java.util.zip` you are still vulnerable to zip slip.